# Guice PrivateModule providing both named and not named injections

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have a PrivateModule defining the following configuration:

```
    public void configure() { 
        Optional<String> annotationName = Optional.ofNullable(config.getString(ANNOTATION_NAME_KEY));
        if (annotationName.isPresent()) {
          bind(SqlClient.class).annotatedWith(named(annotationName.get()))
              .toProvider(this::createClient)
              .in(Singleton.class);
          expose(SqlClient.class).annotatedWith(named(annotationName.get()));
        } else {
          bind(SqlClient.class)
              .toProvider(this::createClient)
              .in(Singleton.class);
          expose(SqlClient.class);
        }
   }
   
   @Provides
   private SqlClient createClient() {
        return SqlClient.init(config);
   }
```

This private module is initialized multiple times vs json configuration, providing multiple sql clients with different configurations. This works ok when all of the configurations have ANNOTATION_NAME_KEY: calling

```
  @Inject
  @Named("AAA")
  SqlClient aaaClient;

  @Inject
  @Named("BBB")
  SqlClient bbbClient;
```

returns expected results. But when i have a json configuration that has no ANNOTATION_NAME_KEY key, this to provide a solution for case without named annotation like

```
  @Inject
  SqlClient defaultClient;
```

I get the following exception:

> A binding to my.SqlClient was already configured at my.SqlClientModule.configure(SqlClientModule.java:110).

Am I missing something or the entire idea of mixing named and non-named injections are wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The latter, you should be using the same `@Named` just using different dependencies based on the environment.   `@Named("AAA")` would accept `10.x.x.x` for production, but `localhost` (or something along those lines) for test.

Comment: @kendavidson  there is no problem with Named. i want to have also a default version without Named, created in the else part of the configure().

Comment: I understand that, but that's what I'm saying will not work.  As soon as you have one Named, you cannot do an un-named from my experience.  The question is, why do you want a default without Named when you already have AAA and BBB?  What is the difference?